# Controlling the load order of css files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm loading a main.css file after the jquery ui css loads:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  <-- jQuery CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery.Jcrop.css" />  <!-- not used here -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css" />   <-- my main.css
```

This is the order I want because I overwrite some of the theme styles.

But in reality, the jQuery css loads after main.css because two transfers are forked:

[image: CSS load graph]

How can I be sure that my main.css loads after the jQuery theme css?

Thanks

Comment: What counts is the order they are specified in the HTML file.

Comment: The browser will process them in the order you specify regardless of the time to load. The only exception being if either fails to load.

Comment: @Pekka웃 is correct - that chart is a visual aid to show if you have resources tying up total page load time, not the order. CSS includes, and in fact all html elements, will load precisely in the order they are encountered on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order they are specified in the HTML file is the only thing that should count for the final result.

Either way: load your jQuery UI CSS from elsewhere, I don't think `code.jquery.com` is supposed to be used as a CDN.

That should bring down loading times massively. 2 seconds is way too much for a measly style sheet.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. The jquery css was getting precedence because its rule was .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {cursor : move;} while my main rule was .ui-dialog-titlebar {cursor : default;} Apparently throwing another class in gives the whole rule higher specificity.  Thanks for the heads-up on the jquery css load. Can you recommend a CDN that works well for you?

Comment: I guess Google's is a good choice: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui although AJC points out below that code.jquery.com is supposed to be ok, too. Not sure why it takes that long for you.

Answer (score 1):

Also use the minified version if you append `.min` just before `.css` you will get the minfied version.

check it out..

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css

@pekka I think code.jquery can be used as a CDN on the jQuery website in the footer it says `CDN: //code.jquery....`

Comment: But if it really takes 2 seconds to load, it doesn't seem worth using. (Although I'm really surprised to see such catastrophic loading times from jQuery's official source)

Comment: Agreed, however the minified version for me took 10ms, I am on a pretty quick dedicated fibre though!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  It doesn't really take 2s to load the jquery css.  I was reading the timeline wrong. Here's the correct image:

[image: css loading]

The jquery-ui.css is only 7.5KB so there's no difference really between the full and min version. All the time is in connecting and waiting.

When I finish developing the 750KB index.php code I'll minify and  gzip it to get its time down.

Thanks for your help.